# Incoming call not showing name

Tags: ios, call, quickblox

I have implemeted [QuickBlox](https://quickblox.com/developers/Chat) audio/video call.
I have an issue, When a incoming call received it shows a number instead of user name.
Please find the attached image.
How to replace this with caller user name.

[image]

Comment: Three things. First, I didn't down-vote your question but it seems like it was because you've shown us nothing in the way of code. It might help someone who can help you. Second, have you tried to contact the vendor? Finally, this may be a dumb question, but why/how can you have caller ID work when there's "No SIM"? If that isn't an issue, did you set everything required in the request/response correctly? (That's where code might help.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not Quickblox functionality, check [Apple CallKit Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/callkit): **Identifying Incoming Callers** section.

> For example, consider a user who is friends with Jane in a social
>   networking app, but who doesn’t have her phone number in their
>   contacts. The social networking app has a Call Directory app
>   extension, which downloads and adds the phone numbers of all of the
>   user’s friends. Because of this, when the user gets an incoming call
>   from Jane, the system displays something like “(App Name) Caller ID:
>   Jane Appleseed” rather than “Unknown Caller”. To provide identifying
>   information about incoming callers, you use the
>   addIdentificationEntry(withNextSequentialPhoneNumber:label:) method in
>   the implementation of beginRequest(with:).